# Generate single file from Hadoop's MultipleInputs and MultipleOutputs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

When I use 2 files in `MultipleInputs` and 2 files in `MultipleOutputs` then I get 2 files as reducer output. How setup to get only 1 single file as reducer output?
Is the only possibility is to use `SequenceFile`?

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,  new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,  new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class);

FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "outMin", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, DoubleWritable.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "outMax", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, DoubleWritable.class);
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. MultipleOutputs is used to write output data to multiple outputs. In case if you are mentioning that reducer outputs should be accumulated into one file for outMin and one file for OutMax use  job.setNumReduceTasks(1);   If in case if you are talking about using MultipleInputs alone refer the following link for sample program https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs

Comment: You get one file per reducer

Comment: I am getting 4 files except 2 files!